# Slide over and split view in iPad simulator

Tags: ipad, ios-simulator, multitasking, splitview

iOS 9 introduced *slide over* and *split view* for iPad. How do I simulate these features on an iPad simulator? I have tried swiping from right on iPad Air 2 simulator with no luck.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To simulate slide over: drag from the right edge (starting from a point very close to the edge).

To simulate split view: tap on the small white bar on the left edge of the slide-over app.

[image: small white bar on screenshot]

See [this WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=205).

**EDIT** (Thanks to @qix, @Bogdan Weidmann, @Solomon)

Supported devices:

- iPad Air+, Mini 2+ for slide over
- iPad Air 2, Mini 4, Pro for both slide over & split view

Project requirements:

- Built with iOS 9+ SDK
- Supports all device orientations
- Use launch storyboards

Comment: At first, I could not find the small white bar you mentioned. But I found if want the app to support split view, the app has to fulfil 3 requirements.

i. Build with iOS 9 SDK

ii. Support all device orientations

iii. Use launch storyboards

Comment: Well all those requirements were fulfilled for me, since I created my project from scratch. You gotta do them yourself if you upgraded from an old one I guess.

Comment: The white bar also doesn't show up if you are in an app like the Settings app which doesn't itself support split view. To test split view, open an app like the Notes app instead.

Comment: worth writing it here one more time: iPad 2 Simulator **doesn't** support Slide Over at all, iPad Air supports **only Slide Over** and iPad Air 2 **can do both**!!

Comment: Do not forget to uncheck toggle "Requires full screen". It can be found under target settings > general tab or in your plist.

Comment: This list of supported devices is also relevant: http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/iphone/iphone-faq/iphone-ipad-ipod-touch-models-full-partial-ios-9-support.html, i.e. iPad Air+, ipad Mini 2+ for slide over, and Air2/Mini4/Pro for split view

Answer (score 24):

I found that dragging from the right in the simulator didn't work for me (in XCode 9.2).

Instead I had to run my app. Then slide up from the bottom, to get the Dock. Then pressing and holding on Safari, I could drag the icon to the right hand side of the screen. The screen responded, and I could let go. The simulator re-arranged to show a split view.

Comment: This worked for me, but here's some further clarity. I loaded Safari (the app I was testing) and then without returning the home screen, dragged slightly from bottom just enough to expose the dock. Then I chose a different app icon from the dock, and dragged this to the right side bar as explained above.

Answer (score 23):

In Xcode 11 if you cannot activate the swipe from the right or bottom edge, **enable device bezels**.  You can then begin swiping from just over the edge of the bezel.  Whereas without bezels you would end up resizing the window.

Comment: Thanks for this. Enabling bezel is the key to being able to swipe up and get the dock.

Answer (score 4):

Doing it the first time, I'll tell you that the steps need to be done meticulously correct. Otherwise it won't work.

1. See the bezel: Simulator >> Window >> Show Device Bezels
2. Open an app you want
3. Make the iPad Dock show: Tap the the bottom center of the bezel and pull it up. (OR just find the app through spring board’s search)
4. Drag the other app you like from the dock but **don't let go of your finger** until you completely pull it **to the edge of the screen** and you see your iPad showing a nice split view. If you let go too quick then the app would just show on top of the other. It won't be a split view.

Keep pulling til the edge. Don't let go yet, otherwise it wont Safari won't split the screen, it would just float over your app...

[image]

This is good:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can drag & drop the App from docker to your App like this:
[image]

A picture is worth a thousand words
See the gif here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpfHZ.jpg

Comment: Was having trouble with any of the approaches that involved any kind of "swiping from edge" (which was just triggering in-app scrolling…) and this worked for me, because there's a Simulator menu item for opening the App Switcher. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to drag your app on the other open app in the dock and hold it. Check out the below gifs which explains this better.

[image]

Comment: One thing I was missing was to first rotate the iPad simulator into landscape mode. Thank you for your video!

Answer (score 1):

I tried this one

`defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator AllowFullscreenMode -bool YES`

and it worked for me

the reference was: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFPUgQpUmuE

Answer (score 1):

if you're on Xcode 11 and still not able to get it to work make sure your project doesn't require full screen.

To verify go to your Target settings > General tab > Requires full screen and disable it.

Also I noticed that you've to start dragging from the black border of the iPad Pro simulator in order to get it to work. hope this helps someone.