# Xcode 12 Testing app in simulator on split screen

Tags: swift, xcode

Is it possible ? I check ipad air 4, ipad 8 gen, ipad pro in all simulators, multitasking cannot be started.

Comment: Not tested on last version but : https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/85087 ? And the bezel might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30912631/slide-over-and-split-view-in-ipad-simulator (see the different answers)

Comment: Its not working...

Comment: That's my answer you're talking about, and it does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One counterexample is sufficient to disprove the hypothesis:

[image]

Screencast showing how to do it (time sped up for purposes of the demonstration):

[image]

Comment: It's a good news. Can you describe how to do it?

Comment: Exactly the same as you would do it on a device. Only sloooowwwwweeeeerrrrrrr.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly and importantly, you need to **show device bezel**: In `Xcode`, select menu `Window/Show Device Bezel`.

Then it will work like real device: Slide from bottom to show dock, drag the app you want to the right side of opening app.